# Network Adapter not Found on Lenovo IdeaPad 1 15ADA7

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo

I recently changed my Lenovo laptop (IdeaPad 1 15ADA7) from Windows to Linux, however when I installed it I realized I dont have wifi. And algo I cant find which wifi card the laptop has. I've found the device Name to be Realtek Broadcom 5762.

I have already tried these commands that I found on a forum online

```
Download Dependencies
sudo apt-get update

apt-get install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
Install 'fix':
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git -b v5 cd rtw89 && make && sudo make install
load module:
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

Ive also tried these

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

However, the second command "apt-get install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git" gives me the error "Package make has no installation candidate" so I cant proced with the solution.

On the second set of commands I get the error with the command make "No targets specified and no makefile found"

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "I cant find which wifi card the laptop has." Let's find out. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, add the output of `$ . /etc/os-release && echo $NAME $VERSION && uname -a` to your posting.

Comment: It is either a Realtek or a Broadcom; not both. Broadcom 5762 is ethernet, not wireless. Please post the result of the requested commands, not a digest.